# Why doesn't CORS preflight request prompt for (or reuse a connection where) client certificates (are sent)?

Tags: ssl, cors, client-certificates

Given a situation where

- a server requires client certificates,
- the consumer is on another origin, and
- wants to do preflight-requiring requests (e.g PUT, POST with content-type json, etc)

is there no way to allow this -- without dropping the client certificate requirement and making them optional?

### Background

You might say "but it does work", but apparently this is considered a bug in Chrome[1].

On Firefox, preflight requiring requests don't go through at all because the preflight doesn't succeed (because "a strictly non-client-certified" TLS connection is made to the server)[2][3]. Yet, when e.g loading an image from the certificate-protected server, it does prompt for a client certificate and succeeds if provided.

In both [2] and [3] the "confused deputy problem" is cited as the reason, same issue is mentioned in the Fetch specification[4] (ctrl-f to find it everywhere). What I don't get is how is this a confused deputy problem? If a preflight is made, it prompts the user to choose a certificate, so the user knows about it being sent. And the final say still goes to the reply for the preflight -- doing a credentialed preflight *doesn't skip the preflight sequence*.

Secondly, the `OPTIONS` method (used in the preflight) shouldn't be side-effecting, so there is no deputy to be confused there either.

How come one has to make certificates optional to make this work? Optional certificates seem strictly worse security wise, and also adds a configuration burden to stop non-client-certified and non-`OPTION` requests from going forward.

1. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=775438
2. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1019603
3. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1511151
4. https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol-and-credentials

Comment: The preflight purpose in this case is basically to ask the server if it allows getting requests *from frontend JavaScript code running in a browser at some particular origin* that include credentials. So it doesn’t make sense for the browser on its own to preemptively send credentials as part of the very preflight request it’s making to ask that question, and for the server to then be surprised it’s unexpectedly getting credentials from frontend JavaScript code running in a browser, and possibly from some origin the server knows nothing about. The point is to give the server a chance to opt in

Comment: @sideshowbarker But the problem is that TLS lives *under* HTTP, so there is no chance for a certificate requiring server to reply to preflights. Also, from the front end I can link to images on the certificate requiring server and get the certificate prompt, and also send credentials unexpectedly.


I.e what if specifically client certificates are out of scope for CORS credentials?

Comment: Second point: the credentials aren't unexpected, as the server is configured to always require them.

Comment: The problem is not that the credentials are not expected, it's that the request might be.

Comment: @Anne and hence the preflight beforehand, no?

Comment: That's the request I'm talking about.

Comment: @Anne Isn't the interpretation that preflight carries no credentials
invented by the spec?

Comment: I do understand why CORS is for, i.e open up for opt-in cross-origin
requests. I also *haven't* researched the other two forms of
credentials that are not sent, namely cookies and HTTP auth -- perhaps
for those cases allowing nor expecting those for a preflight makes a
lot of sense. (But I don't know.)

Comment: But what the specification supposedly says is that client credentials
are *explicitly not to be sent* in preflights either. This creates a
chicken-and-egg situation, becouse how would one perform a preflight
if a certificate-protected server rejects the request at the doorstep
and the server won't even get a chance to respond? I.e one might say
that requiring a certificate for preflights is broken. Yet another way
to spin this is that specification for preflights has broken client
certificates for the modern web, where deploying front-end
cross-origin is normal.

Comment: For my immediate use case, and since the situation isn't going to
change, and I do need to support Firefox, I'm forced either to switch
to POST-with-multipart or actually lift the mandatory
certificates' requirement. But for what benefit? Both appear to be
strictly worse than a full-on client certificate authenticated server
(with proper preflight responses set up! Given that it doesn't
restrict setting up TLS.)

Comment: You have the option to open an issue at https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues to raise this to the awareness of the people involved in work on the spec. This isn’t really a problem that anybody here on Stack Overflow can provide a solution or workaround for. Any solution would necessitate a change to the spec and change to browser implementations. So the issue tracker for the spec is the place to get consideration of this problem, and to have discussion of any possible solutions.

Comment: https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/1181